# send information of a drop down list to database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a dropdown list that have some job information that get information from a table in a data base, now i need when a user choose a item of dropdown list and when press submit, send selected item of dropdown to relative table.

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'relative';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
if($selected){
$ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table (job_name) VALUES ('the selected item of list')";
$saved=mysql_query($ins );
mysql_close($con);}}
```

and here is how i fetched information of a table into my dropdown list:

```
        <?php

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'job_list';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  $db_table",$con);
echo "توانمندی مورد نظر خود را انتخاب نمایید: ";?><br/>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="home.php">
<?php
echo '<select>';
echo '<option></option>';
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{
echo '<option value="'.$amch['job_id'].'">'.$amch['job_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>'; ?><br/>

<textarea name="textaria" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

        </form>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: What happend after you ran this code?

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should set a name for `Select` tag in HTML code:

```
echo '<select name="job">';
```

Then you can get selected option using `$_POST` variable:

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table (job_name) VALUES ('" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['job']) . "')";
```

Comment: i have this error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\source\untitled.php on line 247......... line 247 is $ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table (job_id) VALUES ($_POST['job'])";

Comment: Try again with new change!

Comment: now, i do not recognize name of list!! Undefined index: job in C:\wamp\www\source\untitled.php on line 247

Comment: Did you set a name for select tag as i mentioned in answer?

Comment: Are you using this code on home.php?

Comment: yea i used it. will that work in php tag as html tag? no im working on my test page "untitled.php"

Comment: it just move to home.php after clicking on submit, no more actions

Comment: You should add your code on first section to this file.

Comment: oki used two pages. untitled.php for fetch of first table and send.php for send to second table. but table is empty yet. code is true cuz i used a echo command but something is wrong hamvatan!

Comment: lol my table name was a bit wrong! thanks dadashi ;)